# A lot of unknown sources..?

Tags: java

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ''   at
>   java.util.Formatter.checkText(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)   at
>   graphics.shape.toString(shape.java:24)    at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)   at
>   graphics.Test.main(Test.java:7)

The following code corresponds to the above error:

```
 package graphics;
    public class shape {
    public double radius, angleT, angleP, arcT, arcP, wS, h, wanted;
    public double sH, w, overlap,tR;

    public shape (double shortHeight, double width, double overlapDistance, double tR){
        sH = shortHeight;
        w = width;
        overlap = overlapDistance;
        this.tR = tR;
        radius = Maths.getRadius(sH,w);
        angleT = Maths.getAngleTotal(sH, w);

        arcP = Maths.getArcPartial(sH, w, overlap);
        angleP = (angleT*(arcP/arcT))/2;
        wS = 2*(Math.sin(angleP)*radius);
        h = radius * Math.cos(angleP);
        wanted = tR * wS;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Given:/n"
                + "Short Height: %f\n"
                + "Width: %f\n"
                + "Percent Overlap: %f/%\n"
                + "Projector's throw ratio: %.2f\n"
                + "<Calculated>\n"
                + "Radius: %.2f\n"
                + "Angle Total: %.2f degrees\n"
                + "Arc Total: %.2f\n"
                + "Angle Partial: %.2f\n"
                + "Arc Partial: %.2f\n"
                + "Width smaller: %.2f\n"
                + "Height of smaller: %.2f\n"
                + "[wanted length]: %.2f\n",sH,w,overlap, tR, radius, angleT, arcT, angleP, arcP, wS, h, wanted);
    }

}
```

The Maths class is:

```
package graphics;

public class Maths {

    public double radius, angleTotal, arcTotal, arcPartial, anglePartial;

    public static double getRadius(double heightSmall, double width){
        return ((Math.pow(heightSmall,2))+ (Math.pow((width/2),2)))/(2*heightSmall);
    }

    public static double getAngleTotal(double hS, double w){
        return 2*Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2((w/2),((getRadius(hS, w))-hS)));
    }

    public static double getArcTotal(double hS, double w){
        return Math.toRadians(getAngleTotal(hS,w))*getRadius(hS, w);
    }

    public static double getArcPartial(double hS, double w, double overlap){
        return (getArcTotal(hS, w)*(1+overlap))/2;
    }
}
```

but I don't think this part is the problem.... The test class has:

```
package graphics;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        shape demo = new shape(1,6,.25, .5);
        System.out.println(demo);       
    }    
}
```

I don't know why the `toString()` in the shape class isn't working...

Comment: The following looks funny `+ "Percent Overlap: %f/%\n"`

Comment: yeah.. i just realized that lol ty

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return String.format("Given:\n"
                + "Short Height: %f\n"
                + "Width: %f\n"
                + "Percent Overlap: %f%%\n"
                + "Projector's throw ratio: %.2f\n"
                + "<Calculated>\n"
                + "Radius: %.2f\n"
                + "Angle Total: %.2f degrees\n"
                + "Arc Total: %.2f\n"
                + "Angle Partial: %.2f\n"
                + "Arc Partial: %.2f\n"
                + "Width smaller: %.2f\n"
                + "Height of smaller: %.2f\n"
                + "[wanted length]: %.2f\n", ...);
```

**Output:**

```
Given:
Short Height: 1.000000
Width: 1.000000
Percent Overlap: 1.000000%
Projector's throw ratio: 1.00
<Calculated>
Radius: 1.00
Angle Total: 1.00 degrees
Arc Total: 1.00
Angle Partial: 1.00
Arc Partial: 1.00
Width smaller: 1.00
Height of smaller: 1.00
[wanted length]: 1.00
```

- `/n` changed to `\n` in first line
- `"Percent Overlap: %f/%\n"` changed to `"Percent Overlap: %f%%\n"` (% sign needs to be escaped using a % sign)
- It worked when I gave it 12 float values.